Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS Freezing During Video Calls/Video Playback – Audio Continues, No Input Response
I'm encountering a frustrating issue with my system that has been running fine for years, but recently it has started freezing randomly once a day. Here's my setup:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 @ 2.80 GHz
RAM: 32GB
Graphics: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2
Laptop: HP ProBook 450 G5
My system freezes unexpectedly, and the problem seems to happen during video calls (Zoom, Meet, etc.) or when watching videos on social media (both Chrome and Firefox). The symptoms are as follows:
The screen freezes, but I can still hear audio and, in the case of video calls, I can continue talking with others, though the screen remains stuck.
Neither the external USB mouse/keyboard nor the internal keyboard/trackpad respond.
Ctrl+Alt+Delete does nothing.
After waiting 10–15 minutes, sometimes the system starts responding again, but most of the time, I have to perform a hard reboot.
I checked system temperatures using sensors around crash times, and everything seems to be within normal ranges.
Given that audio continues working and the screen remains stuck visually, I suspect it's something related to the graphics card or a driver issue. Does anyone have suggestions for troubleshooting or fixing this?
Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

This question is similar to: Screen suddenly flashes, becomes grainy and shows visual artifacts. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I experiencing the same issue. There's a thread 'Screen freeze on Ubuntu 22.04 when playing video in Chrome or FF' (https://askubuntu.com/q/1524318/452725) from 2024-08-24 reporting on the same problem. Some of them report that switching from Wayland to Xorg (on the login screen) seems to avoid the problem. I just switch to see if that helps me.

FWIW, OP posted the same question in Ubuntu Forums thread 'Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS Freezing During Video Calls/Video Playback – Audio Continues, No I' on 2024-09-23 (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2501116&p=14207227).

I was able to resolve the issue by switching from Wayland to Xorg. But ultimately, I have no clue what the cause of the problem was.
